# 503 error on azure cloud service

Tags: azure, http-status-code-503, azure-cloud-services

We use Azure and have problems with our Cloud Service last two days.
We get 503 error on site. It looks like one of web-roles reboots sometimes. But in dashboard all of them works fine.
Application Insight and Logs doesn't show any problems. CPU, Memory, Exception rate - all OK.

But I found one interesting moment. SQL queries average time grew to 5 seconds. But I checked it on database, it worked normal. This means that 5 seconds is not execution time but connection.
It looks too much for trace inside data center.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can find a solution of this problem?

Comment: Did you tried IntelliTrace. You can enable it next time you publish. Then you can download the result when you meet 503. It will give you, hopefully, very detailed information on what's going on in your code.

Comment: Thanks, IntelliTrace is a good solution, but Application Insights gives detailed information too.
Anyway, today we caught the moment when Azure tried to Stabilize web-role. It helped us find some exceptions which gave information about possible problems.

It is timeout exception in the roles communication module. Appeared because of overflow blob container. We had over 15M files in one of them.
Now we cleaned container and wait for result.

Comment: Application Insights is a new feature I'm not familiar with. But I will take a look now. Thanks!

Comment: Try it, very helpful tool :)

Comment: The problem came back.
Looks like roles lose network in some moment. We got a lot of "connection failed" exceptions.
Restarts roles/new deployment didn't help.

Now we deployed service in another data center and test this solution

Comment: hey, I'm experiencing similar errors. Did you ever find a solution to this, dbondarev?

Comment: @skhro87 yep. Google for "IIS Rapid Protection". When your app generates a lot of exceptions in short time IIS stops application pool and you get 503 error.

Comment: @dbondarev You can write your last comment as an answer in hopes of saving frustrated people's time like me getting this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your app generates a lot of exceptions in short time IIS stops application pool and you get 503 error.
For more details google for "IIS Rapid Protection".